# ODP Managed Provider for .NET failed to load. service could not be found

Tags: asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2015, oracle-manageddataaccess

When I open Visual Studio 2015 for a project that uses **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess** I get an error

> An unhandled Microsoft.NET Framework exception occurred in w3wp.exe"
>   message.

When I look at the Event Viewer I see this message for devenv

> An unexpected error occurred in the ODP Managed Provider for .NET. 
>   The data provider 'ODP Managed Provider for .NET' failed to load.  The
>   {6a61ae9b-cbff-48d1-a377-51ed463b37bc} service could not be found.

Setup

- OS is Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2015
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess NuGet package v12.1.24160419
- Solution has

  - Web API Project .NET Framework 4.5.2
  - 2 class library projects .NET Framework 4.5.2
  - Unit Tests Project .NET Framework 4.5.2

I can call my `WebAPI` service without issue and the Unit Tests run fine so it seems to just be a problem when I launch Visual Studio. It's more of a nuisance than anything.

I found some articles mentioning to check machine.config for the Oracle.`ManagedDataAccess` Client entries and they do exist in my machine.config in Framework and Framework64 folders.

Anyone found a resolution to this before?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio. This fixed it for me.

I know that I'm replying to a question that has been open for 2 months. 
But it has caused me a lot of headaches and half my working day. So hope it helps anybody having this issue.

Comment: A reinstall didn't resolve this for me. What version of VS are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using vs2010, vs2013 and vs2015. With the debugging profile i had this issue, but in release without debugging(ctrl-f5) it ran fine. The main setup I use is vs2013 with Oracle client 11.2 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: You could also try to remove the oracle software and delete the directory where oracle previously has been installed. Then remove the oracle keys from the registery in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE Software/oracle and Software/SysWow64/oracle and make sure that there are no more oracle dll's in the Global Assembly Cache. After this also confirm that there are no dll's left in c:\Windows\Assembly. For this last one you have to use the command prompt as the windows explorer won't allow you to view this directory. After this reinstall all required oracle software.